# Deserializing to multiple possible types with ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, dropbox-api

I am attempting to create a consumer of Dropbox's JSON API in C#, using the ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries (the HttpClient class, etc.) and the ReadAsAsync<>() method.

For most methods something like this is adequate to my needs:

```
return this.HttpClient.GetAsync("info").Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccountInfo>().Result;
```

However, the API has [a method to get the metadata, for either a file or a folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) (same operation). I would *like* to have distinct classes for files/folders, but I don't necessarily know which I'll be getting back when calling the API to get the metadata.

If I were using JSON.NET directly, I believe that I could specify a custom ContractResolver to determine which class it should deserialize to based on the content (one of the data fields is a true/false flag that will tell me which is applicable). However, I don't see any way to do this through what HttpClient exposes.

So. Before I go for a hacky fallback (deserialize to base class, re-deserialize to the appropriate child based on the flag), is there a way to programmatically have HttpClient figure out which class the JSON should deserialize to?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to simply get the result as a string using [`ReadAsStringAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx), and then feed that into JSON.NET yourself, using a custom [`IContractResolver`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) as you suggested. This isn't quite as elegant as being able to set it up beforehand like you suggested, but it is better than deserializing/reserializing.

```
string json =
     this.HttpClient.GetAsync("info").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, ....);
```

As an aside, you should probably not be using blocking things like `Result` or `Wait()` on `await`able methods, since it can cause deadlocks when misused (see the articles [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and [Avoiding Deadlock in Async/Await](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23103.c-avoiding-deadlock-in-asyncawait.aspx)). In a web context, this usually means your controllers should have its actions written as `async` methods. The way to write it here would be:

```
string json =
     await (await this.HttpClient.GetAsync("info")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, ....);
```

Comment: Thanks for the async references. I'm not surprised that I'm doing it wrong; that's definitely something that I know I need to spend some more time learning about!